# Reverse Array, Let Elements in New Array Equal Length of Original Array Elements - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse, string-length

Trying to solve [this kata on Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/ultimate-array-reverser/train/javascript).

I've been able to reverse the array into a string, but haven't been able to assign this string into individual elements of a specified length. I tried:

```
function ultimateReverse (array) {

 let newArray = array.join("").split("");
 let reversedArray = newArray.reverse();
 return reversedArray.join("");

}

console.log(ultimateReverse(["I", "like", "big", "butts", "and", "I", "cannot", "lie!"]));

//!eiltonnacIdnasttubgibekilI
```

But the outcome that we want is:

`["!", "eilt", "onn", "acIdn", "ast", "t", "ubgibe", "kilI"]`

So according to the original array, the length of the first element should be 1, the length of the second element should be 4, the third should be length 3, and so on...

Is there a way to split a string into array of elements, each of a specified length?

I thought of creating an array of the lengths of the items from the original array by doing:

```
function ultimateReverse (array) {

let elementLengths = [];

let newArray = array.join("").split("");
let reversedArray = newArray.reverse().join("");

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let element = array[i];
  elementLengths.push(element.length);
}

return reversedArray + " " + elementLengths;

}

console.log(ultimateReverse(["I", "like", "big", "butts", "and", "I", "cannot", "lie!"]));

//!eiltonnacIdnasttubgibekilI 1,4,3,5,3,1,6,4
```

Now if I can just split the string into elements in an array based on the length of the original elements...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First construct the full reversed string, eg

```
!eiltonnacIdnasttubgibekilI
```

Then, from an array of the initial lengths (which can be done with a `.map` in advance), iterate over that array and `slice` that length from the reversed string, and push to an array:

```js
function ultimateReverse(array) {
  const lengths = array.map(({ length }) => length);
  let reversedStr = [...array.join("")].reverse().join('');
  const result = [];
  lengths.forEach((length) => {
    result.push(reversedStr.slice(0, length));
    reversedStr = reversedStr.slice(length);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(ultimateReverse(["I", "like", "big", "butts", "and", "I", "cannot", "lie!"]));
```

You could also keep the initial reversed data as an array that you `splice` from, instead of reassigning `reversedStr`:

```js
function ultimateReverse(array) {
  const lengths = array.map(({ length }) => length);
  const reversedChars = [...array.join('')].reverse();
  return lengths.map(
    length => reversedChars.splice(0, length).join('')
  );
}

console.log(ultimateReverse(["I", "like", "big", "butts", "and", "I", "cannot", "lie!"]));
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance - it certainly works. Can you please explain a little more about `{length}` on line 2 - length is an object, in this case?

Comment: That's destructuring. `{ propName }` inside a parameter list extracts the property named `propName` from the item at that position in the parameter list, and puts it into a variable named `propName`. The `.length` of a string is an integer.

Comment: Please explain the reason why the parens wrapping `{ length }` are needed. Otherwise `error: unknown: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: @sandthorn I think it's because the parser sees `{ length }` without parentheses as an *object*, and then chokes up when it sees `=>` following the object. Not entirely sure, I'm going to look into it. If I don't see a good answer to it, I'll probably write up a Q+A myself once I figure out what's going on

Comment: Some explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this via revering the string then mapping through it and essentially "cutting it to pieces" with `substr` like this:

```js
let reverse = arr => { 
  let i = 0, rData = [...arr.join('')].reverse().join('')
  return arr.map(x => {
    let str = rData.substr(i, x.length)
    i += x.length 
    return str
  })
}

console.log(reverse(["I", "like", "big", "butts", "and", "I", "cannot", "lie!"]))
```

Basically map through the original array and for each string `substr` from the combined reversed string as much as the current x length is.